# MSB4016: The build stopped unexpectedly because the "WorkflowCentralLogger" logger failed unexpectedly during initialization

Tags: tfs, build

I am trying to build my solution and its failing with below error.

***error MSB4016: The build stopped unexpectedly because the "WorkflowCentralLogger" logger failed unexpectedly during initialization. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

The build was working fine. but suddenly we started facing above issue from last week.

I tried searching over internet and also tried some troubleshooting like, Check for out-of-disk space also restart the server.

Could you please help me ?

Regards
Ashish Sapkale

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? If you are using XAML build, you can try to login the build agent machine and use MSBuild command line to build the project to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: I am using XAML Build, and I can reproduce the issue on Build Controller using same MSBUILD Command.

Comment: @AshishSapkale I'm stuck with this, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is related to build tool. Try to download Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and install on your build agent machine, or repair/reinstall your VS. Choose the tool version o download:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Answer (score -1):

The following post suggests to clean the user cache and reboot -

http://xavierdilipkumar.com/post/2015/02/13/error-MSB4016-The-build-stopped-unexpectedly-because-the-WorkflowCentralLogger-logger-failed-unexpectedly-during-initialization.aspx